# MIPS, how to invert a series of numbers in a while loop (a rapid method)

Tags: mips

I coding an exercise but I have find a little problem... My exercise ask me that convert a character (keyboard input) in:

- ASCII code
- Binary code
- Hex code

without the MIPS syscall. 2 points on 3 are solved for now but in the point 2 I have find my problem... When I insert a letter for example, the binary code is invertited (see below)

Give me a character: a
ASCII: 97
Binary 10000110 (The real is 01100001)

Exist an easy method to invert this number? I leave the code below.

```
print_binary:
#move the function parameter in t0
move $t0, $a0

#Show a message
li $v0, 4
la $a0, m3
syscall


while:
    #check if my counter is 8(conversion on 8 bit)
    beq $t2, 8, end_loop
    #Divide the number
    div $t1, $t0, 2
    #move hi in t4 to show in video
    mfhi $t4
    #Counter
    add $t2, $t2, 1
    #move for another division
    move $t0, $t1

    #Show hi for every division
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t4
    syscall

    j while


end_loop:
    jr $ra
```

I don't use the array very well, so I would avoid this method if possible...

Thank you

Comment: For the ASCII code, no conversion is necessary, just print the character you've got using the `print_int` system call. For binary/hexadecimal, write a loop where you get the topmost 1 bit / 4 bits of the value, convert that into a character in the range `'0'..'1'` / `'0'..'F'`, print the character, shift the value 1 / 4 bits to the left, repeat until you've gone through all bits.

Comment: @Michael can you explain me better? thank you